# Is it possible to use ESLint in editor and not in project?

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

We have a somewhat old project with a lot of typescript "issues". Missing return types, use of any, etc.

I wanted to add ESLint to the project to ensure that we follow some strict rules, but if I do this on project level I cannot compile if ESLint finds errors. But I don't want refactor 1000 files... so is it possible to do this on IDE level instead of project, so that ESLInt does show me the errors but Angular can still compile my project?

With the `Angular Language Service` plugin I can set `strictTemplates` config in the plugin instead of in my `tsConfig`. So it does show me templating errors, but Angular still compiles, since the `strictTemplates` setting doesn't apply to the project.

Comment: You can enable ESlint in your IDE only and check the errors.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on how to do it?

Comment: What's the IDE you use?

Comment: Sorry, Visual Studio Code. With an `eslintrc` file I get > `No ESLint configuration (e.g .eslintrc) found for file: /app/pages/authenticated/insights/insight-page/insights-page.component.ts
File will not be validated. Consider running 'eslint --init' in the workspace folder`

Comment: Yeah, in VScode you have to create config file. But if you use WebStorm for example. there are linter already in the IDE and works well.